# Why do I got php code when accessing phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to user phpymadmin on Ubuntu 22.04, I've already install LAMP server. When I accesss `localhost/phpmyadmin` on my browser, I get the following php code[image]

I've already installed phpmyadmin and apache. I tried

> sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin

But I still can't access phpmyadmin. What can I do to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see php code it's beacause php is not installed :

```bash
sudo apt install php
```